# Which Android SDK packages needed for developing?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have previously asked about which version of the SDK do I need and was told that I only need the latest and the rest are included in it.

But looking through the Android SDK manager I see there are many other types of packages. So can someone please explain what is going on there?

More specifically:

1. Do I need **system images** if I don't use an emulator? (I tried it in
   the past and it was too slow.)
2. Do I need the "android sdk **build tools**" for any but the latest
   version? And how about the "android sdk **tools**" (only 25.2.5)? is that just a different name for the same thing? And what about "android sdk
   **platform tools**" (only 27.0.1) - Same thing?
3. Do I need only the really ***latest*** "sdk platform" and not even the latest *major* version plus the latest minor version? e.g. Is 8.1.0 enough, or do I need 8.0.0 as well and the 8.1.0 is only an addition to the 8.0.0?

Any warning of pitfalls when uninstalling packages welcome. ("Oh. If you uninstall an already installed package, Xamarin will croak. Wasn't that obvious?!"...)

**EDIT** (in response to request below)

[image]

Comment: The reason this question has been put on hold (according to the box under the question now): `[questions like this] tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` Huh? Did you read the question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No you do not. However Android Emulator is really fast now-a-days given their 2.0 update, HAXM updates, and Quick Boot feature.
2. No, you only need the `build-tools` and `platform-tools` version relating to your major `compileSdkVersion / $(TargetFrameworkVersion)`. i.e. If compiling against API 27 you need `build-tools` and `platform-tools` v27 or greater. A general rule of thumb is to keep all Android SDK tooling to the latest. If you cannot use latest, then ensure they are all on the same **major version (i.e. v27).**
3. Yes, you only need the latest SDK Platform that you will compile against.

Android APIs are additive in the sense that if you install Android 8.1, you will have APIs for every level up to 8.1.

You can install `system-images` of other SDK Platforms for testing purposes as you do not need to install the API level to deploy to them.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that in No. 2 you also mean that `tools` and `platform tools` are the same as `build tools`. Correct?

Comment: As for No. 3, I would also like to confirm that you are referring to sub versions as I mentioned. i.e. That 8.1.0 does in fact include 8.0.0 so the latter is not needed.

Comment: Yes, typically you want all of these to be on the same major API level you are compiling against. `SDK Tools` however usually falls behind. For example `SDK Tools` is 26.1.1 atm vs. others being 27+.

Comment: Yes, APIs are additive meaning that 8.1 includes all of 8.0 and below.

Comment: And lastly, Why did you include `system-images` in No. 3? Or was that meant to be an independent line?

Comment: Because it's a common misconception that you need to download the API level in order to deploy to the AVD of the same level for testing purposes. I added this line as it's a common point of confusion.

Comment: Your comment about `SDK Tools` confused me. You're saying that it "falls behind", but there doesn't even _exist_ an `SDK Tools` for anything but 25.2.5, just as _there is no_ `platform tools` for anything but 27.0.1!

Comment: @ispiro Can you attach a screenshot of the SDK Manager you are using? You are probably using the "deprecated" one - https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/9eed5704d4601196435bf169620d3186 You can also view the revisions released here - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html However be noted that this isn't updated often as the latest is 26.1.1 from Google Manifest Stable Feeds.

Comment: I have the latest VS2017 version installed and up to date. See the newly added screenshot in the question.

Comment: Yup that's the old SDK Manager. You would need to update your SDK Tools to be >= 25.2.5 to use the new one. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-sdk/#SDK_Manager

Comment: Sorry clarifying on the earlier comment, it needs to be > 25.2.5, not equal.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you do not use an emulator you do not need any system image.

2) Yes and no. If you go with Android Studios Android SDK Manager instead of Visual Studios implementation than you are mostly good to go with the latest one. There might be circumstances that require an older version but that are rare situations. One that comes to my mind: Using the Xamarin Android Visual Designer instead of source view or the one from Android Studio.

3) It depends on the amount of devices you want to support. With the SDK-platform you define which set of apis you want to use. It also defines how many of the android marketshare you will reach. If you go with the latest chances are very high that you will only reach 1 or 2 percent of the market. [See Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)